# Is $2^n -1$ finitely many times the product of consecutive primes?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

This question was asked at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465274/is-2n-1-finitely-many-times-the-product-of-consecutive-primes) but recieved no attention at all. 
Here it is:

Are there finitely many $(n,k) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ with $2^n-1=p_1p_2\cdots p_k$ ?

$p_1=3,p_2=5 , ...,p_k$ are consecutive odd primes in ascending order.
An example is when $n=4, k=2$:
$2^4-1=3\cdot 5=p_1p_2$
Are there finitely many $n$?
I tried to use [Zsigmondy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem)
without success.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this will contradict the XYZ conjecture: http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.4147

Comment: In fact it seems like except for $2^4-1$, no $2^n-1$ can be a product of **any** consecutive primes (unless it itself is a (Mersenne) prime)

Comment: As for OP, it is subsumed by [another question here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/163173/powers-of-2-and-the-products-of-initial-odd-primes?rq=1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\let\dvds\mid$Yes. By Zsigmondy's theorem, $2^{12}-1$ has some prime divisor $p_s$ not dividing $2^i-1$ for $i<12$ (in fact, $p_s=13$). Now, if $2^n-1=p_1p_2\dots p_k$ with $k\geq s$, then $p_s\dvds 2^n-1$, so $12\dvds n$ and hence $3^2\dvds 2^n-1$, which is impossible. Thus only the cases with $k<s$ are left.

Comment: I see, thanks. One minor remark - one hardly needs any theorems nowadays to check that $13$ does not divide $2^i-1$ for $i<12$ :)

Comment: Surely. I just wanted to emphasize that we do not need to determine this prime explicitly.